# How can I default my spring boot application to application/xml without killing /health?

Tags: json, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm working on a spring-boot (1.4.0-RELEASE) MVC Groovy app which will present an XML api. By default Spring seems to wire up Jackson which marshalls my response objects to JSON, however I want it to default to responding in XML without requiring any `Accept` header from clients, hence I configured the default content type as follows:

```
@Configuration
class SpringWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
  }
}
```

This works just fine, however when running our tests I discovered that calling `/health` now returns a 406 status code and no content (it previously returned a 200 and a JSON response).

Having reverted the above change I thought perhaps I could force each controller to explicitly set the response content type via the use of a `ResponseEntity`, in doing so I tried the following in my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/blah",
                method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<MyResponseObject> getProgrammeRestrictions(@PathVariable String coreNumber) {
  // Generate response object (code snipped)...
  new ResponseEntity<MyResponseObject>(myResponseObject,
                                       new HttpHeaders(contentType: MediaType.APPLICATION_XML),
                                       HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

However this doesn't seem to influence the response type, which still defaults to JSON.

In a nutshell it seems that setting a default non-json content type breaks the actuator healthcheck. Is there someway to force the healthcheck bits and bobs to disregard the default setting and always be generated in JSON?

Has anyone else experienced this? Grateful for any pointers as I'm a bit stuck here.

Many thanks,

Edd

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `jackson-dataformat-xml` dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then, make its `XmlMapper` available:

```
@Autowired
private MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter;

@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
    // this returns an XmlMapper, which is a subclass of ObjectMapper
    return mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper();
}
```

It works when sending a request from the browser (http://localhost:8080/health), the returned result is in XML (chrome sends the header `Accept: */*`).

When sending the request programmatically, you still have to pass `Accept: application/json` in your header since the service expects this media type, but the returned result will be XML.